# Multiple Facebook Connect

Tags: authentication, facebook

I'm building a website photo contest and it has two registration forms on the same page, one for the models and another for users who will vote.
do I have problems if I integrate facebook connect to each form?
I really need two forms because the registry for models allows to upload photos, fill in details and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is generally not a great idea, nor necessary, to have two apps for the same product/site. You can easily just use one app integration for both features - only asking for the extra permissions and data when the user tries to do something which requires them.